Is there a difference between "weighted average" and "double-weighted average" when processing a signal?
I have come across the term "dual-weighted average" and "double-weighted average" to determine the peak of a discrete data set. I understand the concept of a weighted average; it can be described as:
$$W_{average} = \frac{\sum^n_i w_i x_i}{\sum^n_i w_i} \tag{1}$$
where $w_i$ is the weight of the data point and $x_i$ is the data point in question. So, if trying to find the peak of a discrete data set for a wave signal, the weight can be attributed to the distance to the peak/centre.
However, when told to calculate the location of the peak of a wave that is detected by a row of detectors (resulting in a discrete data set) I have been told to use a "Dual-weighted average" for this purpose. How does this formula vary?
When asking Chat-GPT, the answer given to me was that
$$W_{average} = \frac{\sum^n_i w_i x_i I_i}{\sum^n_i w_i I_i} \tag{2}$$
where $I_i$ is the intensity of the signal at each point. Is this correct?
